# Customizing anchor tag in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am currently using following syntax in menu in default.ctp of my CakePHP 3 application

```
<li class="first"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>users/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span><br>Dashboard</a></li>
```

Now the problem arises if I try to write the  tag in CakePHP 3 syntax which is as follows:

```
<li><?php   echo $this->Html->link('Dashboard',['controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'view','_full'=>true]);?></li>
```

As you can see that there is no place to put tag in above and because of that glyph disappear from menu.

Is there a way around that which I can't find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `'escape' => false` to solve your problem

```
 <li>
        <?php   
            echo $this->Html->link(
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span><br>Dashboard',
                  array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'view','_full'=>true),
                  array('escape' => false)  // important  
                );
        ?>
 </li>
```

For cakephp 3

```
 <?php   
         echo $this->Html->link(
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> <br>Dashboard',
             ['controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'index','_full'=>true],
             ['escape' => false]  // important 
         );
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting along with the HTML link  helper, you can use shorter way, less php code [Url Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html)

```
<?= $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'view','_full'=>true]); ?>
```

And create menu / html link as

```
<li class="first">
 <a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'view','_full'=>true]); ?>">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
   Dashboard
 </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `escapeTitle` option.

```
$this->Html->link(
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span><br>Dashboard',
    ['controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'view','_full'=>true],
    ['escapeTitle' => false]
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-th-list')) . "Dashboard",
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'), 
    array('escape'=>false)
);
```

Comment: I have tried both the above answers. Output should be like this
<li class="first"><a href="http://localhost/abc/users/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span><br>Dashboard</a></li>.
But it is like this
<li><a href="http://192.168.1.177/abc/users/view">&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-th-list&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</a></li>